# Is the Cognito Forms website HIPAA compliant?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am inquiring about the security of the data patients would enter on the forms. Are these forms secured? Is your website HIPAA compliant?

Comment: Please note that this site is not the official support page for Cognito Forms. You probably need to contact them directly. For more information about _this_ site, please take the site [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Yes, Cognito Forms are secure, you can lean more about our Data Security in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/74/entries/data-security).

We do offer HIPAA compliant forms after you have as signed BAA on file with us, and your on the Enterprise plan. You can learn more about our HIPAA compliance in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/78/entries/hipaa-compliance).